# How to arrange a sub-array for Quick sorting algorithm?

Tags: quicksort

Alghorithm : Quick sort .

idea : devide and conqure .

steps :
1- find the pivot point from array like first element .
2- partiotioning the array so that elements are smaller than pivot point are  in the left side and ones are bigger in the right side .
**3- sorting both sub arrays (recursion)**

Question : i know all of the steps but i don't know how to sorting sub arrays  in step 3 . i can't find any example that explains this ending part .

Example :

[image: if you look at this you see that both sub array are unsorted and we should complete step3 with recursion method to solve this and this is my question .]

if you look at this you see that both sub arrays are unsorted and we should complete steps with recursion method to solve this and this is my question .

[image]

but can you explian this for me ?

Comment: Its just a simple recursion. Call `quicksort` on both sub arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conceptually simplest way is to simply use the same algorithm recursively to sort the sub arrays; hence why it's labeled as recursion. As long as the base cases for very small arrays are correctly defined, this will yield a correct result.

As an example, let's Quicksort some alphabet, using first symbol as pivot:

```
sort(FHDEBACG) -> sort(DEBAC) F sort(HG)
```

Then, we recursively sort `DEBAC` and `HG`. I'll demonstrate with the former:

```
sort(DEBAC) -> sort(BAC) D sort(E) -> sort(BAC) D E
sort(BAC)   -> sort(A) B sort (C) -> A B C
```

thereby getting the desired result:

```
sort(DEBAC) -> A B C D E
```

In practice, Quicksort implementations are often modified to sort small enough (sub-)arrays with Insertion Sort, which usually exhibits superior performance for sufficiently small input arrays. Arrays and sub-arrays larger than this are sorted, as above, usually by recursively applying the same algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much . can you take a look at this top picture ?   i can't undrestand it .  in  your example we just normally divide the elements between p.p yes ?

Comment: @jasmine The top picture seems utterly irrelevant to Quicksort; it appears to portray the Bubble Sort algorithm.

Comment: Yes i think so . Thank you ,  i really learned it because of your help .